# What are acceptable changes to make to a user's computer during make install?

Tags: installation, makefile, configuration, root

I have been experimenting with **make** and makefiles.  I have a shared library that I'm now installing into *${PREFIX}/lib* instead of hard-coded */usr/lib*, but now it can only be found by other projects if **ldconfig** has been run with the proper directory since the workstation was started.  That is not acceptable behavior.

The solution I found to this particular problem is to add (a resolved) *{PREFIX}/lib* to */etc/ld.so.conf*, either directly or by adding a new *.conf* file in */etc/ld.so.conf/d*.  This is easy enough for me to do on my own system, and I know how to write makefile rules so an end-user won't have to solve this problem, but I am uneasy with the makefile solution.  Since I can't find any online suggestions to do this, I'm concerned that it may be taking too much liberty with the end-user's computer.

That introduces my general question: what am I allowed to change on an end-user's computer during `sudo make install`?  Being root during install gives me almost unlimited abilities to make software changes, but obviously some things should be out-of-bounds.  Where can I find guidelines about what well-behaved installers can or should not do?

Comment: Short answer: IMO it should never be required to run `make install` as `sudo` unless you're trying to copy files into restricted locations like `/usr/lib` etc.  I don't know what you mean by "found by other projects".  Other projects should set their linker flags to find your library at both link time and runtime, if it's not installed in the default locations.  It's not your responsibility to set up their system to find them.  That's how it's always worked, and how it should work.

Comment: My shared library processes command line arguments.  I want the library to be used by command-line applications.  When I installed the library in `/usr/lib`, the applications could always find the library.  When I changed my makefile to install to ${PREFIX}/lib, with PREFIX set to `/usr/local`, applications could no longer find the library.

Comment: On the subject of using `sudo` to run `make install`, that seems to be how I install most other applications.  My sample size is likely too small.  Supporting your opinion, yesterday I was not allowed to install some scanner software as root.  That is another topic about which I would eagerly read guidelines.

Comment: All I can say is what I said above: if you want to install things into root-owned directories like /usr/lib or /usr/bin, then clearly you need `sudo`.  If you want to install things into your local home directory, then you should not need `sudo`.  As for applications using your library, like I said above it's up to them to locate it wherever they installed it.  It's not on you as the library author to do that.  Maybe they want to do it by modifying `ld.so.conf`.  Maybe they want to do it by setting `RPATH`.  Maybe via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a wrapper script.  That's on them.

Comment: Sorry for addressing your single comment with several.  So makefiles that install software are responsible for finding libraries that are not in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and to use both -L and -rpath options for linking?  Otherwise, the end user may struggle to resolve the missing library problem.

Comment: I would think that the default install should just work without much user intervention.  Special cases like altering the install location presumes a sophisticated user who is prepared to deal with resolving conflicts thus introduced.

Comment: You are providing a library.  Users don't use libraries (directly).  Libraries are for developers.  Developers need to know how to link libraries.  If you were providing an application for users to run, then you would need to decide how to allow the user to run that application without doing a lot of messing around with their system.  How each application does that is best decided by that application.  It's not right for library authors to try to make that decision for them.  If they install into the default location it will Just Work.  If not, they want to do something else.

Comment: Anyway, you asked for advice and that's mine: as a (very) long time developer both proprietary and FOSS, it would annoy me if some library I wanted to install and use locally started messing around with my system's settings.

Comment: I appreciate your advice and I accept your expert judgement.  I don't mean to try your patience with many questions, but I'm trying figure out what to do so it "Just Works" for people who might use my programs.  That's why I'm looking for a document about makefile guidelines, so I can understand the larger context and be able to follow best practices in my projects.

Comment: "programs" != "libraries".  Programs should be installed so that users can run them without a lot of extra configuration beyond, possibly. changing their PATH.  Libraries should be installed so that _programmers_ can use them in the way that's most useful to them.  If they want to use them without any configuration they'll install into /usr/lib and it will just work.  If they want to install somewhere else, then only they can know what the configuration should be.  That's my $0.02.  Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229987/discussion-between-chuckj-and-madscientist).